# How to use parallel() of Highland.js in stream programming to achieve parallelisation?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, stream-processing

I am trying to achieve parallelization of streams in nodejs, Following code terminates on adding parallel method in the pipeline.

`let x = [1,2,3,4,5]
highland(x)
   .map(t => t*2)
   .parallel(2)
   .each(t => console.log(t))
   .done(()=> console.log('DONE'))`

ERROR :

`Uncaught Error: Expected Stream, got number`

What is the correct way of achieving parallelization by using highlandjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map`](https://highlandjs.org/#map) creates a single stream, but [`parallel`](https://highlandjs.org/#parallel) expects a *stream of streams*.

See [examples](https://highlandjs.org/#examples), the second one shows `parallel` in action. You could try modifying that `t=>t*2` function to provide its result in a one-element stream:

```
t=>highland([x*2])
```

but this is just an idea from the top of my head, I can not try it.

Comment: @NikhilShinde those code-formatted words (`map` and `parallel`) are links too (that is why they are also blue and underlined).